# Custom window for JavaFX applications

Tags: java, javafx

I have been doing some research and have not been able to find much information.

I have seen many JavaFX projects (Showcased) that tend to have custom windows. I have not been able to find anything within the documentation on how to achieve this within JavaFX.

Is this achieved through Java or Non-Java Libraries?

Something like this [image]

Comment: I would imagine that can be done using JavaFX with an [undecorated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/StageStyle.html#UNDECORATED) stage and a whole load of CSS, perhaps with some custom controls in the bottom row. But what is your actual question? "How was this written?" No-one knows that except the programmer who wrote it. Where did you get the screen shot?

Comment: @James_D I am not after the exact code, but was using it as an example of something that is done using JavaFX. The question was is this type of effect achieved through additional libraries or other languages libraries integrated into JavaFX? The picture was from http://fxexperience.com/category/demo/

Comment: Did it occur to you to click on it and read what it says about how it was written? What possible answer are you expecting other than "here is what it says in the web page you got this from"?

Comment: @James_D i did read it, but this was produced via Photoshop and cut into .png for images. The question still remains, is this the only way this can be aesthetically achieved  or are there any libraries that can be used instead of chopping up photoshop files..I.E an undecorated window, but a custom image as the stage, with the scene in the centre? https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=881481222018466&set=gm.1409599089076498&type=3&ifg=1

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking. Are you asking if there is a library that programmatically extracts portions of a photoshop file for use in JavaFX? (That question would be off-topic for this site, I suspect the answer is "no" but maybe there is something like that out there.)

Comment: @James_D I have replaced the image to better  articulate what I was trying to ask.  The centre part I assumed was the stage with a custom image attached to the window [thought this might have been completed using a separate library].   I am guessing this isn't the case and again what you said earlier "a ton load of CSS". Reason being is my CSS skills are not the best.

Comment: The new image just looks like a scene with a background image, perhaps an image view in the center, and then some controls (buttons, labels, progress bars) that are styled by CSS. You should just try to implement this and post a specific question if you can't get part of it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image result is achived through `JavaFX` existing functions

What you're looking for is a `Undecorated Window` or `Transparent Window`. This makes your window undecorated...

But you also have to set  the `Scene` background `transparent` otherwise the background would be white.

Code to make the stage undecorated is: `primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);`

Code to set the scene background transparent: `scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

*The rest is only a design job...* using `CSS` (A `ImageView` in the middle and `CSS` styled buttons ontop)

P.S.: If the `Stage` is undecorated you can't resize it with the mouse anymore. A good `API` to fix this (make it resizable again) is: [BorderlessScene](https://github.com/NicolasSenetLarson/BorderlessScene)

**---- Wrap Up ----**

1. `primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);`
2. `scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);`
3. --Optional-- use the `BorderlessScene` for resize

Comment: Thank you, I was aware of the undercoated and transparent functions, but hadn't seen it this way and was unable to put 2 and 2 together.

Comment: No problem :). Now have fun and build your own GUI